# Preferred Python twitter API?

Tags: python, twitter

I found at http://dev.twitter.com/pages/libraries#python that there are several Twitter APIs for Python.

I've been using python-twitter for a while but never needed the API Search. Now I need to do a job that includes Twitter searches and I see they are not supported by this lib.

I wonder know which of the listed ones is the appropriated for this task.

Thanks,

**Note:** I used python-twitter 0.6 - svn trunk seems to include searches.

Comment: I need to do searches in a time interval.

Answer (score 18):

[Twython](https://github.com/ryanmcgrath/twython) has proven good for a current project of mine. It seems to be the most up-to-date with the Twitter API.

If you need streaming API support I would recommend [Tweepy](https://github.com/tweepy/tweepy).

Comment: OK, but it seems Twitter API don't let you search in a time interval. You can do this kind of search in the web interface: http://search.twitter.com

Comment: You would have to filter searches based on your time interval on top of the library you use. There's no filter for this in the API so it would have to be done on your end.

Comment: Tweepy is now located here: https://github.com/tweepy/tweepy

Answer (score 1):

I have been using [Python Twitter Tools](http://mike.verdone.ca/twitter/) and like it a lot. It still won't handle your search filtering for you, but you would have to do that anyways.